# Server side OnCheckedChanged not working if i open ASP RadioButtons in Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, modal-dialog, radio-button

I am using following code to open Div in dialog box, which contains a two radio buttons. The server side event is working if I don't open that div as dialog box. But in case of dialog box the postback is working but the checked event is not working.

Following is the code i am using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="row">
    <a runat="server" href="#" onclick="openDialoge()">button</a>
    <%--<button runat="server" id="btn" value="Button" onclick="openDialoge()">dasd</button>--%>
    <div id="popupObject">
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="a" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="a" CssClass="noUnderline" Text="a" OnCheckedChanged="a_CheckedChanged"/>
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="b" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="a" CssClass="noUnderline" Text="b" OnCheckedChanged="a_CheckedChanged"/>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openDialoge(e) {
        $("#popupObject").dialog({
            height: ((400 - 350) * (180 / 100)),
            width: "500px",
        });
    }
</script>
```

Can anybody suggest why is that happening or what should i do to solve that.

Comment: @ChandanHasila Can you please tell me if you tried the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that it does not work using JQuery-UI.  But it does work using bootstrap.  Please let me know if it worked for you also.  I got it to work with a master page and without a master page.

Here it is with a site.master page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="FredWebForm.WebForm2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(function () {
                $("#btn_open_modal1").click(function () {
                    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

                })
            })
        });
    </script>
    <button id="btn_open_modal1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch outer modal
    </button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div style="height: 100px;">
                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="a" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="a" CssClass="noUnderline" Text="a" OnCheckedChanged="a_CheckedChanged" />
                        <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="b" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="a" CssClass="noUnderline" Text="b" OnCheckedChanged="a_CheckedChanged" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="btn_open_modal2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
                        Launch second modal
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```